# Compare sequentially Coma Separated Values from two columns and give matching values - Help Needed

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

Hi I have a challenge where I have to compare the coma separate values from 2 columns (Column A , Column B and find the sequentially comma separated matching values and output to Results column.

Example:

Compare "Column A" values (Coma Separated ) with "Column B" (Coma Separated) and output the sequentially comma separated matching Values (Coma Separated)  to "Result" column

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

*To generate "the sequentially comma separated matching Values", I would like to suggest you VBA code instead of any complex Formula, which is faster and better.*

1. Press ALT+F11 to open VB Editor windows.
2. Select the Sheet from Project Explorer Window.
3. Right click and select Insert, Module.
4. Then Copy & Paste both.

**How to use:** `=GetDiffs1(A2,B2)&", "& GetDiffs2(A2,B2)`

```
Function GetDiffs1(Cell1 As Range, Cell2 As Range) As String
Dim Array1, Array2, lLoop As Long
Dim strDiff As String, strDiffs As String
Dim lCheck As Long


Array1 = Split(Replace(Cell1, " ", ""), ",")
Array2 = Split(Replace(Cell2, " ", ""), ",")
On Error Resume Next
With WorksheetFunction
    For lLoop = 0 To UBound(Array1)
        strDiff = vbNullString
        strDiff = .Index(Array2, 1, .Match(Array1(lLoop), Array2, 0))
        If strDiff = vbNullString Then
            lCheck = 0
            lCheck = .Match(Array1(lLoop), Array2, 0)

            If lCheck = 0 Then
                strDiffs = strDiffs & "," & Array1(lLoop)
            End If
        End If

    Next lLoop
End With

GetDiffs1 = Trim(Right(strDiffs, Len(strDiffs) - 1))
End Function

Function GetDiffs2(Cell1 As Range, Cell2 As Range) As String
Dim Array1, Array2, lLoop As Long
Dim strDiff As String, strDiffs As String
Dim lCheck As Long


Array1 = Split(Replace(Cell1, " ", ""), ",")
Array2 = Split(Replace(Cell2, " ", ""), ",")
On Error Resume Next
With WorksheetFunction
    For lLoop = 0 To UBound(Array2)
        strDiff = vbNullString
        strDiff = .Index(Array1, 1, .Match(Array2(lLoop), Array1, 0))
        If strDiff = vbNullString Then
            lCheck = 0
            lCheck = .Match(Array2(lLoop), Array1, 0)

            If lCheck = 0 Then
                strDiffs = strDiffs & "," & Array2(lLoop)
            End If
        End If

    Next lLoop
End With

GetDiffs2 = Trim(Right(strDiffs, Len(strDiffs) - 1))
End Function
```